# Prestashop 1.7: Fatal error Failed opening required HTMLPurifier.standalone.php

Tags: permissions, prestashop-1.7, htmlpurifier

My client's website was working normally until This warning and errors appeared and the website has become inaccessible:

```
Warning: require_once(/homepages/19/d729760136/htdocs/clickandbuilds/PrestaShop/embout_/tools/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /homepages/19/d729760136/htdocs/clickandbuilds/PrestaShop/embout_/config/config.inc.php on line 136
```

And the error:

```
Fatal error: 
require_once(): Failed opening required '/homepages/19/d729760136/htdocs/clickandbuilds/PrestaShop/embout_/tools/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php'
(include_path='/homepages/19/d729760136/htdocs/clickandbuilds/PrestaShop/embout_/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/homepages/19/d729760136/htdocs/clickandbuilds/PrestaShop/embout_/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/homepages/19/d729760136/htdocs/clickandbuilds/PrestaShop/embout_/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/homepages/19/d729760136/htdocs/clickandbuilds/PrestaShop/embout_/vendor/pear/archive_tar:.:/usr/lib/php7.0')
in /homepages/19/d729760136/htdocs/clickandbuilds/PrestaShop/embout_/config/config.inc.php on line 136
```

I think the problem is because of file permission. But I don't know how to treat it. Any help?

Comment: What happens if you `ls -al /homepages/19/d729760136/htdocs/clickandbuilds/PrestaShop/embout_/tools/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.standalone.php` on the command line? What system user does your web server run as? (And what have you tried so far?)

Comment: The only thing that I did, I contacted the web hosting service and they only asked me to clean or delete harmful files and I don't find that answer really helpful

Comment: Agreed, that's not very helpful. Did you have a chance to find out anything re: my other questions? Asking since it's hard to diagnose the problem without further information. Generally speaking, judging by the error, either the file is not actually there or it's not readable. ("not there" can then in the second step also mean that your autoloading may be looking in the wrong place, but we've got to figure out the basics of your problem first.)

Comment: Well, the file is under /tools/htmlpurifier but with permission 200 not 604. When I try to give it 604, I don't see the debug mode screen anymore (just a message http 500 error)

Comment: What user is it owned by and what user does your web server run as? That said, from the sound of it, you've got only limited access to your hosting environment and are trying to interact with the filesystem through a user interface. You may need to ask your webhoster's support to change the permissions on the file for you.